# Search strings from bulk data

Tags: regex, text, awk, pattern-matching

I have a folder with many files containing text like the following:

```
blabla
chargeableDuration    00 01 03
...
timeForStartOfCharge    14 55 41
blabla
...
blabla
calledPartyNumber   123456789
blabla
...
blabla
callingPartyNumber   987654321
```

I require the output like:

```
987654321 123456789 145541 000103
```

I have been trying with following awk:

```
awk -F '[[:blank:]:=,]+' '/findstr chargeableDuration|dateForStartOfCharge|calledPartyNumber|callingPartyNumber/ && $4{
if (calledPartyNumber != "")
 print dateForStartOfCharge, "NIL"
dateForStartOfCharge=$5
next
}
/calledPartyNumber/ {
for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)
  if ($i ~ /calledPartyNumber/)
     break
print chargeableDuration, $i
chargeableDuration=""
}' file
```

Cannot make it work. Please help.

Comment: Are the digits always at the end of the line? And do you have additional Digits before which shall not be matched? If you do not have Digits  before: [`^\D*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/qV2qC1/1), and if: [`[\d ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/qV2qC1/2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a file with text named "test.txt", below linux shell command will do the work for you.

```
egrep -o "[0-9 ]{1,}" test.txt | tr -d ' \t\r\f' | sort -nr | tr "\n" "\t"
```

Comment: thanks but instead of the desired 4 columns it prints many other columns as well. Can you increase the filter to take the exact headers ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much like Manishs answer:

```
tac test_regex.txt | grep -oP '(?<=chargeableDuration|timeForStartOfCharge|calledPartyNumber|callingPartyNumber)\s+([^\n]+)' | tr -d " \t\r\f" | tr "\n" " "
```

Only difference is, you keep the preceding order instead of sorting the result. So for your example both solutions would produce the same output, but you could end up with different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/[0-9 ]+$/{
    x=substr($0,( index($0," ") + 1 ) );
    gsub(" ","",x);
    a[$1]=x
}
END {
    split("callingPartyNumber calledPartyNumber timeForStartOfCharge chargeableDuration",b," ");
    for (i=1;i<=4;i++){
         printf a[(b[i])]" "
    }
}'
```

`/[0-9 ]+$/` : Find lines end with number separated with/without spaces.

`x=substr($0,( index($0," ") + 1 ) )` : Get the index after the first space match in $0 and save the substring after the first space match(ie digits) to a variable `x`

`gsub(" ","",x)` : Remove white spaces in `x`

`a[$1]=x` : Create an array `a` with index as `$0` and assign `x` to it

`END`:

`split("callingPartyNumber calledPartyNumber timeForStartOfCharge chargeableDuration",b," ")` : Create array `b` where index 1,2,3 and 4 has value of your required field in the order you need

`for (i=1;i<=4;i++){
     printf a[(b[i])]" "
}`  : for loop to get the value in array `a` with index as value in array `b[1],b[2],b[3]` and `b[4]`